# Has anyone had success implementing maxmind's free GeoLiteCity DB on a C# webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, geoip, maxmind

We have several international partners/websites that have complained about their traffic being "stolen" by our domestic site (located in US).  I thought it best to implement a free geoip service to offer a redirect option to our international users to their appropriate site if they happen upon our domestic site.

After researching the free options, I found that MaxMind offers a complete package with an option for fairly accurate IPaddress data (ipV4 and ipv6 included).  In fact, our management strongly suggests the use of MaxMind's implementation.

I recently downloaded MaxMind's free GeoLiteCity.dat and github's C# code for my domestic website.  I found the documentation to be quite vague as it relates to implementing their C# code on anything but a console application.

Before I implemented it on my current website - in my development environment, I successfully tested the implementation of the database, and the API on a console application and then successfully on a aspx page for a mock-website.  I am currently experiencing dreaded "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" errors in my development environment.

I've added the class library for MaxMind and also added reference to that class library.

Has anyone run into issues implementing MaxMind's data while using C# code?  Has anyone successfully utilized MaxMind's data and C# code on a webform?  I would appreciate any insight.  If you can provide a walkthrough of the implementation process and perhaps some sample C# code that works (or worked) for you, I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: This is a huge question and impossible to answer without the code that's failing. I'd suggest putting together the code that's failing and asking a specific question on that failure, rather than asking for consultation on the entire process.

Comment: Thank you, Robert.  The "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error shows up in the stack trace.  The code that is failing is actually a Class provided by the API (LookupService.cs).

Comment: Have you looked at the [GeoIP2 API](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet)? It is available on NuGet, and I think the documentation is generally of higher quality.

Comment: Thank you, oschwald.  I have looked at the GeoIP2 API.  It requires a userID and license key from Maxmind.  I am currently looking at their free database implementation for C#.  MaxMind does not offer troubleshooting/support for their free services.  Their suggestions for support/troubleshooting were the message boards on stackoverflow.  MaxMind even provides a direct link to stackoverflow from their free services page.  Hence, my initial post.  The trouble I am facing is that there doesn't appear to be much information here regarding a C# implementation of their database.

Comment: Oschwald, I am trying to implement your suggested GeoIP2 API for C#.  I followed the documentation accordingly. The line about requiring a license key, etc. is listed on the documentation page regarding the web service implementation; my apologies.  Nonetheless, after debugging my code, there is a "FileNotFound Exception". Is there a specific place the GeoLite2-City.mmdb file should be?  Or A specific manner in which to handle the reference to the mmdb file?  I still find the implementation documentation vague and confusing.  My apologies for the ignorance - I am a 1-yr Junior Web Developer.

Comment: same problem here: this code fails no matter where I place the database in my project:var reader = new DatabaseReader(@"GeoLite2-City.mmdb");  var omni = reader.Omni("x.x.x.x");

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify a full file system path to get it to read the database!! I may have missed something but relative path didn't work no matter what!!

```
var reader = new DatabaseReader(@"C:\Users\[User Name]\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\glocalmvc\glocalmvc\Controllers\GeoLite2_City.mmdb", MaxMind.Db.FileAccessMode.Memory);

        var omni = reader.Omni("1.1.1.1"); // replace it with a real ip address
```

after it worked, it didn't return city name, only country!! what a waste of time! :(